# cleaning html tags from a variable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to clean the html tags from a variable with this value:

```html
<td><a class="css-zwebxb" href="/players/1093743350">Zero Two</a></td>, <td><time datetime="PT2M5.031S" time="1670072352910" title="Saturday, December 3, 2022 12:57 PM">00:02</time></td>, <td class="css-7a8yo0"> <button class="css-sanbnz" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></i></button></td>
```

I attempted to clean the tags by using multiple different functions I found online, like

```
import re
# as per recommendation from @freylis, compile once only
CLEANR = re.compile('<.*?>') 

def cleanhtml(raw_html):
  cleantext = re.sub(CLEANR, '', raw_html)
  return cleantext
```

I get the error: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.
Does anybody know a solution? thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only text from the HTML snippet you can use `.text` or `.get_text()`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<td><a class="css-zwebxb" href="/players/1093743350">Zero Two</a></td>, <td><time datetime="PT2M5.031S" time="1670072352910" title="Saturday, December 3, 2022 12:57 PM">00:02</time></td>, <td class="css-7a8yo0"> <button class="css-sanbnz" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></i></button></td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

print(soup.get_text(strip=True, separator=""))
```

Prints:

```
Zero Two,00:02,
```